# AWS IAM Resource Policy - Issues with NotPrincipal resource policy in secrets manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I am logged in as LeadDeveloperRole in aws console and created a secret in secrets manager. I want this secret to be only accessible to
LeadDeveloperRole and AdminRole, so i used below mentioned resource policy on this secret. While saving this policy it shows an error saying:

"This resource policy will not allow you to manage this secret in the future."

As per my understanding,  Deny + NotPrincipal implies apart from LeadDeveloperRole and AdminRole, no one will have access to this.
Am i missing something here ?

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":[
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/LeadDeveloperRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/AdminRole"
            ]
         },
         "Action": [
             "secretsmanager:*"
        ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111:secret:secretid-xxxx1i"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "NotPrincipal":{
            "AWS":[
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/LeadDeveloperRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/AdminRole"
            ]
         },
         "Action": [
             "secretsmanager:*"
        ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111:secret:secretid-xxxx1i"
      }

   ]
}
```

UPDATED:
updated the policy with explicit allow which is giving same error.

Comment: There's always an implicit Deny. The order in which things are evaluated is: 1. Explicit Deny rules; 2. Explicit Allow rules; 3. Implicit Deny. So in this case you need at least one Allow rule for those two roles.

Comment: Whos creating this policy? If you create it, that person will loose access to it, which is not a good idea.

Comment: @Marcin - I am logged into aws with LeadDeveloperRole and creating this resource policy. But i am not sure why would i loose access to it ?

Comment: Maybe it protects against loosing access when you delete the role by accident. With such policy, even a root user won't be able to access/change the secret.

Comment: @MarkoE - I have tried by adding allow rule but same error. I have updated the new policy in the question.

Comment: @user10916892 It seems that what I have told you is an anti-pattern, so apologies! Reading through this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html#specifying-notprincipal got me thinking that you also need to set the user ARNs (e.g., root) and not only roles because of the way policy is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the account principal to the list of `NotPrincipal`s, as without it a request can be blocked e.g. "`arn:aws:iam::111111111:root`" or just the account ID number.

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html):

> When you use NotPrincipal with Deny, you must also specify the account ARN of the not-denied principal.

Comment: Tried both only account number and  "arn:aws:iam::111111111" in NotPrincipal but same error.

Comment: Sorry, I included the wrong account ARN format (forgot the `:root` at the end). Please try with the proper ARN.

Comment: Also, how are you assuming the `LeadDeveloperRole`? Do you see "LeadDeveloperRole" (only!) in the top-right corner of the AWS console?